# Given that $2x = t + 1/t$ and $ 2y = t- 1/t$, show that $ \dfrac {dy}{dx} =\dfrac{ t^2+1}{t^2-1}$ and $ \dfrac {d^2y}{dx^2} = \dfrac{- 8t^3}{t^2-1}$

Tags: calculus

I'm not the best at Calculus and I don't understand how my teacher got the answer he gave us i'm getting really frustrated, someone please help!!

Comment: Tell us what you have done yourself to try to solve this problem. Have you tried writing $y$ as a function of $x$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You can use 
$$
\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}
$$
for
$$
x=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(t+\dfrac{1}{t}\right) \qquad y=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(t-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)
$$
and you find the first derivative.

We have:
$$
\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{t^2} \right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{t^2+1}{t^2}=\dot y
$$
$$
\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{t^2} \right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{t^2-1}{t^2}=\dot x
$$
so
$$
\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\dot y}{\dot x}=\dfrac{t^2+1}{t^2-1}=y'
$$

For the second derivative you can use the same rule noting that:
$$
\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy'}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}
$$

Comment: How would I setup the problem to get the answer

Comment: I've added something to my answer.

Comment: I'm still confused Calc is hard for me and I still don't see how u get the answer

Comment: If you want to learn calculus you have to do some effort ! Do you know how to calculate the derivatives, with respect to $t$ of $x=\frac{1}{2}(1+1/t)$ using the derivation rules? And do the same for the other functions? Do this and add your calculations to your question, if there will be some mistake I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to do this problem. you have $$2x = t+1/t, 2y = t-1/t \tag 1$$

addition and subtraction of $(1)$ gives you $$t = x + y, 1/t = x-y\tag 2 $$ in particular, multiplying the two equations in $(2),$ we have $$x^2 - y^2 = 1  \tag 3$$  differentiating $(3)$  once, you get $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac xy = \frac{t^2 + 1}{t^2 - 1}\tag 4 $$  differentiating $(4)$ with respect to $x$ gives  $$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{y - x\frac{dy}{dx}}{y^2} = \frac{y^2 - x^2}{y^3} = 2\frac{(t-1/t)^2 - (t + 1/t)^2}{(t-1/t)^3} $$ i will let you simplify the last fraction.

Comment: I got 8t^3/(t^2-1)^3??? is that right?